# Access DOM element with a selector stocked in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am constructing a selector dynamically as following

```
...code before
my_selector = '"[data-my-selector=' + "'" + id + "'" + ']"';
alert( "The jQuery object is : " + $(my_selector) );
....
```

This code stops executing in the alert.

The selector is constructed properly and it's value is "[data-my-selector='453']" (if i `alert(my_selector)`). If i access `$("[data-my-selector='453']")` via the console, it works.

But when i try to access `$(my_selector)` from the console, i get the error 
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "[data-my-selector='453']"`

Do you have an idea what's the error ?

Thank you

Comment: Why the extra double quotes? you didn't include those when you tested in the console.

Comment: The single quotes need `\'` for selector=\''+id+''\ double quotes shouldn't be needed inside [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes shouldn't be part of the variable. When you hardcode the string, you need the double quotes to denote that it's a string.

```
my_selector = '[data-my-selector="' + id + '"]';
```